# PHP7: Sort an associative array by byte value of the combined value of Key and Value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am new to PHP programming and I am trying to create a signed request for an Amazon REST request.  To properly sign the request, I have to sort the parameter/value pairs by byte value (not alphabetically).  They provide a sample set as an example:

```
Service=AWSECommerceService
AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
AssociateTag=mytag-20
Operation=ItemLookup
ItemId=0679722769
ResponseGroup=Images%2CItemAttributes%2COffers%2CReviews
Version=2013-08-01
Timestamp=2014-08-18T12%3A00%3A00Z
```

**Sorted Values**:

```
AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
AssociateTag=mytag-20
ItemId=0679722769
Operation=ItemLookup
ResponseGroup=Images%2CItemAttributes%2COffers%2CReviews
Service=AWSECommerceService
Timestamp=2014-08-18T12%3A00%3A00Z
Version=2013-08-01
```

So, I created an associative array called `$parameters` that holds all those values in this syntax:

```
$parameters = array ( "Service="        => "AWSECommerceService",
                      "AWSAccessKeyId=" => "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE",
                      "AssociateTag="   => "mytag-20",
                      "Operation="      => "ItemLookup"
                    );
```

Is there a method to sort the combined value of the individual key/value pairs concatenated? Or do I have to combine them into a temporary array, sort them, and then put them back into the associative array?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ksort($parameters)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why JYoThl deleted his anwser, [ksort](http://www.php.net/ksort) will do the job just fine:

```
$parameters = array(
    "Service=" => "AWSECommerceService",
    "AWSAccessKeyId=" => "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE",
    "AssociateTag=" => "mytag-20",
    "Operation=" => "ItemLookup",
    "ItemId=" => "0679722769",
    "ResponseGroup=" => "Images%2CItemAttributes%2COffers%2CReviews",
    "Version=" => "2013-08-01",
    "Timestamp=" => "2014-08-18T12%3A00%3A00Z"
);

ksort($parameters);

print_r($parameters);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [AWSAccessKeyId=] => AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
    [AssociateTag=] => mytag-20
    [ItemId=] => 0679722769
    [Operation=] => ItemLookup
    [ResponseGroup=] => Images%2CItemAttributes%2COffers%2CReviews
    [Service=] => AWSECommerceService
    [Timestamp=] => 2014-08-18T12%3A00%3A00Z
    [Version=] => 2013-08-01
)
```

Comment: he need to sort with key and value based . ksort only sort based on key

Comment: Doesn't matter since keys are unique, so there's bound to be a difference there that influences the sorting - anything after that won't matter at all.

Answer (score 0):

use ksort() Sort an associative array in ascending order, according to the key:

```
<?php

  $parameters = array ( "Service="        => "AWSECommerceService",
                  "AWSAccessKeyId=" => "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE",
                  "AssociateTag="   => "mytag-20",
                  "Operation="      => "ItemLookup"
                );
  ksort($parameters);
  print_r($parameters );
?>
```

Comment: I was under the impression that `ksort()` sorted only the key values.  I need to sort the array based on the combined byte value of the key and the value (i.e. "Service=AWSECommerceService")

Comment: Since keys are unique isn't that a bit redundant in this case?